# Trying to sync Exchange WebDAV calendar

Tags: sync, calendar

My wife and I each have work calendars with Outlook / Microsoft exchange. My plan was to have these sync with some calendar on my Ubuntu Server so that they both could be accessed on our phones, tablets, web, etc. in a single calendar. At this point, I cannot access her calendar, and vice versa. I have very little knowledge of how to do this. A few things to note

1) It's fine if the calendars from our work are read only, but they should sync if changes are made

2) our company restricts sharing the calendar (would have been the easy solution) (There is a sharing option in Outlook)

3) There is, however, an option to publish the calendar in Outlook. It says "Publish Online" and then the option to "Publish to WebDAV server". However, I have no idea how to do this (See #4)

4) I have Nextcloud running on Ubuntu. I enabled the calendar app. I then tried to put the supplied address 
https://MY.IP.ADDRESS/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/, into the server section of "Publish to WebDAV" in Outlook, I get an error message in Outlook "Access to the resource denied".  Interestingly, when I replace "/dav/" with "/WebDAV/", it seems to connect once I supply my Nextcloud username and password, but then I cannot get Nextcloud calendar to find the calendar. The *.ics file is just sitting in my Documents folder in Nextcloud. (I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible on Nextcloud)

I'd like to keep the solution as simple as possible. It's only my wife and I trying to read each other's calendar in a single location.

I've looked online, but overwhelmed by DCS, Lightening, etc, not knowing which (if any) would do what I'm looking for.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, you might not like this, **but**  Google calendars sync across all sorts of devices:  Ubuntu (thunderbird), Windows, Iphone, IOS....

Comment: You should comply with the company's policy. If they don't want shared calenders then don't even try to workaround the measure put in place to enforce said policy. It doesn't matter it's between you and your wife. At work she's your co-worker, not your wife.

Comment: I’m fine without google calendars but can’t figure out how to get exchange calendar in there.

Comment: I appreciate the comment regarding work policies. Too complicated to explain here but it’s not an issue having our schedules shared between us.